# “paint”: mass noun vs count noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

> Jackson Pollock dropped paints on canvas seemingly at random. ([Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+random))

I have always thought the noun "paint" is uncountable when referring to color/colored liquid/solid pigment. But the above sentence uses it as a count noun in this sense. I thought it is only countable when meaning different paint tubes.

[The Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/paint_2) seems to confirm my guess, suggesting that "paint" is only a count noun in the meaning *a set of small blocks or tubes containing paint of different colors that you use for making pictures*. Can "paint" be countable when used in the sense of "color" or "pigment"? What is the difference between "paint" as a mass noun and as a count noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many “uncountable” nouns can be used in a "countable form" when they refer to a broader meaning. The notion that using an *s* to pluralize an uncountable noun must be an error is a trap.

Words like *waters, rices, sands,* and *oxygens* are valid plural forms, although some of them are quite rare because you would only use them in unusual contexts. For example, a [scientific textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=3tZiAgAAQBAJ) reads:

> This ratio is variable since two types of O may be distinguished in the silicate anions: bridging oxygens and non-bridging oxygens.

I’m reminded of a debate that raged over at ELU some years ago about the [plural of equipment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70828/what-is-the-plural-of-equipment). The accepted answer was downvoted and drew more than 30 comments and has since been deleted; it read:

> *Equipment* can be both singular and plural. The word *equipments* is wrong/ungrammatical, though its use is prevalent.

Fact is, the use of *equipments* is uncommon, not prevalent, and it’s not necessarily wrong or ungrammatical in those usages.

You’ve uncovered an excellent example with the word *paints*. Most of the time, *paint* can be used to even when referring to a plural. For example, if I go to the store and buy a gallon of yellow paint and a gallon of red paint, I would probably say:

> I bought paint today.

(not, “I bought paints today.”)

But there is nothing wrong with me saying:

> There are many paints at the paint store.

In that case, I might be talking about how there are oil-based paints and water-based paints, latex paints and acrylic paints, matte paints and glossy paints, interior paints and exterior paints, etc.

I think what you say about Macmillan is on the right track, but off just a little bit:

> The Macmillan Dictionary seems to confirm my guess, suggesting that "paint" is **only** a count noun in the meaning a set of small blocks or tubes containing paint of different colors that you use for making pictures. [emphasis added]

I think the word “only” is misplaced there; I think a better way to phrase it would be:

> The Macmillan Dictionary seems to confirm my guess, suggesting that "paint" is a count noun **in contexts such as** a set of small blocks or tubes containing paint of different colors that you use for making pictures.

It isn’t practical for a dictionary to list every sense of how a word can be used; the best dictionaries can do is provide a suite of general examples.

Your original sentence could probably be written either way; I would consider both grammatically correct:

- Jackson Pollock dropped paints on canvas seemingly at random.
- Jackson Pollock dropped paint on canvas seemingly at random.

However, the array of paint on a Pollock canvas is so widely varied, from an art perspective, it almost seems a shame to use the singular. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed, informative answer! There are points that I don't fully grasp but will spend a lot of time on.

Comment: English can use the same word to talk about the type of a thing in addition to a thing itself. If X is a type/kind of something, and you want to talk about multiple types/kinds of X, then X is countable.  *I bought several paints = I bought several types/kinds of paint* - *I used all the paint on the side of the house - there was only 1 type/kind of paint used*.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. This is a rather unconventional use of *paints* which is intended to suggest the set of small tubes of paint that the dictionary mentions. The basic meaning is *Jackson Pollock dropped different colors of paint on canvas seemingly at random*. The use of *paints* suggests the source of the different colors, as well as the fact that he used different colors. If the sentence used *paint* instead of *paints* it would include the meaning of using a single bucket of paint.

Comment: +1 https://www.google.com/search?q=%22artist%27s%20paints%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en